# Фамилии с двумя и тремя Ё в паспортах СССР и РФ

Tags: ономастика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как могут быть записаны фамилии с двумя и тремя буквами Ё в произношении в паспортах СССР и РФ, например, такие фамилии, как Тёлёгёнов с тремя буквами Ё или Трёхдёнов с двумя Ё, а также Тёрёчик, Шёгрён, Шёстрём и т.п.?

Знаю, что не у всех в официальных документах, а именно в паспортах, фамилия с Ё в произношении ёфицирована, т.е. записана с буквой Ё (например, записана в паспорте не *Королёв*, а *Королев*). Меня интересуют только фамилии с двумя и тремя буквами Ё в произношении, но может не всегда в написании в официальных документах, а именно в паспорте. Как они могут быть записаны, может возможен вариант написания и через Е (Телегенов, Трехденов, и т.п. Слышал, что в какой-то период в советское время букву Ё приравнивали к Е и писали по усмотрению.
Разъясните, очень прошу! Давно мучает этот вопрос. Спасибо.

(Ссылки на список фамилий с Ё: https://vgd.ru/STORY/yofamil.htm, https://sheba.spb.ru/lit/yo-famil.htm и ещё http://www.yomaker.ru/yofamil.htm.)

Answer (score 1):

Трудно понять, о чем, собственно, вопрос.

Возможно ответом будет упоминание о разъяснении Верховного Суда, официально закрепляющего возможность двоякого написания фамилий - через Е и через Ё. Эти варианты считаются одной фамилией со всеми вытекающими юридическими последствиями.

Есть Постановление Верховного Суда РФ от 23 марта 2015 г. N 305-АД14-4997 с аналогичной позицией.

Подробнее на Правовед.ru: https://pravoved.ru/question/1515873/

Comment: @Роман Да. Если распространить решение суда на все случаи. Сложность-то не в том, как запишут, а в том, как с этим потом жить. Пока решения касались в основном Пенсионного Фонда.