# Написание и произношение фамилии в СОР (паспорте)

Tags: фамилии, документы

Существует фамилия ТрЁхдЁнов, как она будет записана в СОР ребенка? И еще вопрос, если будет записано с одной Ё в этой фамилии, будет ли она произноситься иначе, например, если запишут *ТрехдЁнов* или *ТрЁхденов*?

Comment: Не понимаю - почему фамилия, если она уже существует, должна как-то измениться при записи в Свидетельство о рождении?

Comment: С «ТрехдЁновым» наверняка будет проблемка из-за безударной Е: будут переспрашивать.

Answer (score 2):

Вопросы совершенно умозрительны, но это еще полбеды. Какое это отношение имеет к русскому языку?!

> Существует фамилия ТрЁхдЁнов, как она будет записана в СОР ребенка?

В соответствии с семейным кодексом фамилии в свидетельствах о рождении пишутся так, они они записаны в документах родителей или по их *письменному* заявлению (что уже редкость и возникают сложности). Либо (в редчайших случаях) по решению суда: если на то есть какие-то особые причины. Есть только одна оговорка, касающаяся двойных фамилий. В случае несоблюдения этого правила документ скорее всего будет признан недействительным - и подлежит замене.

> будет ли она произноситься иначе, например

Произношение фамилии ни правилами русского языка, ни семейным кодексом никак не регламентируется. Вообще при чем тут произношение и написание?!

Могу только одно добавить, фамилии с Е и Ё считаются эквивалентными. Разумеется, речь не о произношении, а о признании принадлежности документа. Иногда, правда, загсы и другие органы вольничают - и тождественность приходится доказывать опять же в суде. Но правоприменительная практика такова, что все решения принимаются в пользу гражданина (или стороны, требующей признания тождественности).

Answer (score 1):

Вот что пишет ["Российская газета"](https://regnum.ru/news/polit/1205550.html) (15.09.2009).

Верховный суд России поддержал огромное число граждан, которые вошли в группу бюрократического риска из-за двоякого правописания фамилии, имени или отчества. Если человек имеет, например, букву "ё" в фамилии, его можно узнать и без точек над "е". Так полагают в высшей судебной инстанции...
Большинство документов изготовляются с использованием компьютерной техники, клавиатура которой не всегда предусматривает двоеточие над "е". Поэтому государственные конторы нередко отказывают гражданам в точках над буквой: как техника позволяет, так и напишут. А там, где заполняют бланки от руки, могут и уважить седьмую букву алфавита (ту самую "е" с точками).
Пару лет назад ведомство в своем письме разъяснило, что нельзя отказывать гражданам, когда они просят расставить точки над "е".
Однако есть важный нюанс. **По закону точки обязательно ставить лишь в тех случаях, когда без них теряется смысл слова.** Если же перед вами, скажем, Соловьев или Ежиков, можно обойтись и без двоеточия: каждому понятно, о ком речь.

Сколько букв **ё** имеется в фамилии (или имени) — не столь важно, главное — чтобы отсутствие или присутствие точек эту фамилию не искажало. И, конечно же, если **ё** присутствует в документах родителей, то должно быть и в свидетельстве о рождении (будут разночтения — точно набегаетесь).

Стоит также помнить, что "е" и "ё" имеют значение при написании фамилии на других языках (при переводе документов или получении паспорта другого государства):
Семенов — Semenov, Семёнов — Semjonov;
Теречик — Teretšik, [**Тёрёчик**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%91%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA,_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8) — Tjorjotšik.

**Дополнение**

У меня в школе был удивительный педагог русского языка и литературы.
Я до сих пор помню ее пример, касающийся особенностей склонения фамилий, если "ё" меняется на "е":
**Лён** (Р. п. — Льна или Лёна, Д. п. — Льну или Лёну...);
**Лен** (Р. п. — только Ле́на, Д. п. — только Ле́ну...).

Я считаю, что даже при малейшем недопонимании или возможности извернуть значение фамилии (или имени), буква ё должна присутствовать в документах.

Comment: *По закону точки обязательно ставить лишь в тех случаях, когда без них теряется смысл слова.я*  Я очень надеюсь, что это формулитровка - блажь неграмотного корреспондента, а не законодателей, в чьей грамотности я, впрочем, тоже сомневаюсь. Нет такого закона. И быть не может, слишком он субъективный В части "узнавания". Это первое. А второе:, правило, которым регулируется написание буквы Ё  не распространяется на имена собственные.

Comment: Как же так, _Behemothus_?! Полгода назад Вы в своем ответе давали похожую (правда, усеченную) ссылку, с **такими же** словами. И ничего — не возмущались ничьей неграмотностью. _Подробнее на Правовед.ru: «По закону точки обязательно ставить лишь в тех случаях, когда без них теряется смысл слова»._  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456103/%d0%a4%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%81-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%a1%d0%a0-%d0%b8-%d0%a0%d0%a4

Comment: Эти слова из комментария юриста (в чьей квалификации есть большие основания сомневаться - хороший юрист никогда не скажет "по закону", не назвав и дав ссылку на этот закон). Я не имею к этому никакого отношения, скорее всего даже не читал. А ссылку давал не на этот текст, а на решение суда (Постановление Верховного Суда РФ от 23 марта 2015 г. N 305-АД14-4997), в котором ясно сказано, что фамилии, написанные через Е и Ё не различимы в расках юридической правктик.